# SAPUi5 oData Model remove with deferred group ID is not reflecting changes to table in batch mode

Tags: odata, sapui5

- I am using `oData model V2`. `SAPUI version 1.36.8`
- All `oData model properties` for batch mode are on.
- All changes are collected to one batch request but there is not
  `connection to binded items` in table.

Is there common issue for that?

Comment: Binding between table controls and ODataModel v2 works properly in 1.36.8. I may not understand your question fully though. It doesn't indicate what goes wrong, whether you see any error messages, what you've tried to make it work etc. Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: I get item path from columnListItem that was selected, and remove from model by item path.  model.remove(path,{groupId: "myGroup"}).
I can see in model that delete request was collected to deferredRequests, but this change was not reflected in table items

Comment: After a `remove`, the model should refresh itself, unless you add the request to a deferred group. In that case, you need to call `submitChanges` in order to get them sent to the back-end. Once the `delete` requests have been sent to the back-end, the model should refresh itself and changes should become visible.

Comment: my application concept is collect all changes in frontend and send them all together to backend.. I am sure that after submitChanges it will show previous changes (after automatic refresh model)

Comment: Why wait? Just sent changes immediately when the user changes something in the UI. This also prevents complaints from users claiming they lost hours of work because their changes have not been persisted while they work.

Comment: Backend should get some rows together.  it will cause to one specific operation in backend RFC.  As I see this "wait" does not refresh ui from model local changes

Comment: You can add functionality to the back-end to store some sort of 'draft' document. At least, that would be the route I would take...
If you really need to be able to send all your changes in one batch, you may need an intermediate JSONModel in which the user makes changes. Once the user is done and presses save, you could turn their changes into individual requests of your ODataModel, to be sent to the back-end in once batch.

Comment: Ok.  I am checking this approach. Thanks a lot